# How can I solve a conflict when publishing artifacts with classifier to GitHub Packages that share a pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, github-package-registry

tl;dr: I'm trying to solve [this](https://github.com/levyfan/sentencepiece-jni/actions/runs/511004164) issue.

I have a project which builds a platform-dependent JAR and adds a classifier according to the [os-maven-plugin](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.github.levyfan</groupId>
<artifactId>sentencepiece</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2</version>


<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <!-- ... -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I build and publish the artrifact with `mvn --batch-mode deploy` to GitHub Packages, I'm met with a conflict error. This is because the artifacts share a pom (`sentencepiece-0.0.2.pom`), but the JAR artifact is determined by the `os-maven-plugin` value (`sentencepiece-0.0.2-XYZ.jar`).

How can I inject this plugin-defined property at build-time to create unique artifact names?

Comment: Why do you need the classifier?

Comment: Because it's a platform-specific JNI artifact

Answer (score 1):

The items `artifactId` and `version` cannot be influenced by plugin generated properties. To influence them, the property must be given on the command line (or maybe in the POM directly).

So we are left with the classifier.

You need to build all artifacts with classifiers in the same build. So you need to change the build in a way that it builds for the different OS in one go. I don't know whether that is possible (depending on whether you can build e.g. for Windows on Linux) but it seems to be the only "Maven way" solution for you problem.

Of course, you could still try tricks like deleting the POM after you have deployed it, but if possible this should be avoided.